# Difficult issue when implementing multithreading for a function which returns a value

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

TokenCache class is passed to Facebook class to do `save()` and `load()` tokens. `TokenCache` has these functions:

```
public abstract void save(Bundle bundle);
public abstract Bundle load();
```

Now I want to do that saving and loading in multiple threads, so I run a `AsyncTask` in `load()`. The problem is it was  already designed to return a Bundle! How to implement it so that the value only returned when the `AsyncTask` finishes?

Comment: If it only returned a value when it finished, it wouldn't really be an AsyncTask, now, would it? What you need to do is refactor it such that it takes in an anonymous class with a single method that accepts that return value as an argument, or some other such mechanism for handling the result asynchronously.

Comment: yes, it's function which returns value. It's designed as abstract for developer to give implementation for it. The problem is the loading could be a long-time operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply have a field of Bundle in your TokenCache implementation that your load() method returns. Just make sure you don't yet pass a reference to the TokenCache to FB until that Bundle is initialized by some init(bundle) method, e.g.

```
  static class BundleRetrievalTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bundle> {

        @Override
        protected Bundle doInBackground(String... strings) {
            return someLongOperationThatFetchesBundle(strings[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onPostExecute(bundle);
            MyFacebookTokenCache tokenCache = MyFacebookTokenCache.init(bundle);
            doSomethingWithCache(tokenCache);

        }
    }

    static class MyFacebookTokenCache extends TokenCache {

        private Bundle mBundle;

        public MyFacebookTokenCache(Bundle bundle) {
            mBundle = bundle;
        }

        public static MyFacebookTokenCache init(Bundle bundle) {
            return new MyFacebookTokenCache(bundle);
        }

        @Override
        public Bundle load() {
            return mBundle;
        }

        @Override
        public void save(Bundle bundle) {
            //todo
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {
            //todo
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but Facebook uses Bundle bundle = tokenCache.load(); everywhere in its code. Do I have to replace all of them by calling your Task everywhere? It works but not really what I want.

Comment: Who cares that FB uses it everywhere. The only instance of a TokenCache that FB has is yours where the bundle is initialized already.

Comment: Also, can you explain to us the mysterious reason why the bundle needs to be retrieved asynchronously?

Comment: ^ Because I want to get it from server, it's a long-time operation. BTW Where could I call BundleRetrievalTask?

Comment: @Emerald214 wherever it's relevant ;) Create that class and call new BundleRetrievalTask.execute(someString)//or nothing if you don't need a string..

Answer (score 1):

You might use a callback mechanism. In the AsyncTask, after load() finished, call a callback method to do operation based on the returned bundle.

Comment: If I implement like that, the load() function will be meaningless. Because the work TokenCache does is loading, so I can't give its task for an outside AsyncTask as you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static BundleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    public Bundle result;
    private final CountDownLatch latch;
    public BundleAsyncTask(CountDownLatch latch){
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    public void doInBackground(){
        //get the bundle
        latch.countDown();
    }
}

public Bundle load(){
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    BundleAsyncTask task = new BundleAsyncTask(latch);
    task.execute();
    try{
        latch.await();
        return task.result;
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

btw: I don't actually understand why you want to use AsyncTask here.

Comment: Not a joke. I just answer the question though I don't know why use `AsyncTask` here. If you want to use `AsyncTask`(I mean the mechanism), I think this is the only way.